# How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML list items like this:

```
<ul id="fruits">
 <li><a href="#">Mango</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
</ul>
```

User will not see these items, as we are hiding them all with style `display: none;`.
User can search these items from below `input` field:

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="fruitSearch()" placeholder="Search fruits">
```

When user start searching for a fruit name on the `input` field, it will list the matching names, just like google search suggestions.
using the below the JavaScript for search:

```
function fruitSearch() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("fruits");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and show those who match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working as designed & expected until here, once the user clears the input field all the fruit list items `<li>` are visible now instead of hiding.

How do I reset the list items & hide them all, when user clears the `input` field?

https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/cjbwomof/

Comment: just test the value of your input first, and make a special case if it is empty. In this special case, hide them all..

Comment: @paper1111, thanks. That was typo & corrected.

Comment: Even after changing to </li> your search is not working.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to achieve what a datalist already can without coding. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp Whether it is preferable or not depends on the browser support you need I suppose.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal it's not working because he is missing `<a>` tags inside his `<li>` tags i have explained that in my answer.

Comment: Yea,saw that :) I posted it because OP said it was working as expected,So.

Comment: @RMo since `datalist` cannot have `<a>`, i did not used it

Comment: @edisoni.1337, again in hurry missed `<a>` tags, updated now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need to change your html. You need to add `<a>` inside your `<li>` tags because in your javascript code your get content from `<a>` element.

```
<ul id="fruits">
 <li><a href="#">Mango</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can make a condition to check if length of input is more than one

```
function fruitSearch() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("fruits");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    if(input.value.length == 0){
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }else{
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }
    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjbwomof/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Start your function with if statement to check the value if it is ""  then according to that decide if you have to complete the rest of code or not

```
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
 input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
 if (input.value==''){
 document.getElementById("fruits").style.display='none';
 }
 else{
 // the rest of the function
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tip: You should add an event listener instead of using inline events.

```
    if (document.GetElementById('searchInput').value == '')
    {
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++)
        {
            li[i].style.display = none;
        }
    } else {
        // REST OF CODE
    }
```

Because your function gets called on every `KeyUp` event, simply putting the 
  if statement inside the function will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery `keyup` to get the real-time case-sensitive search. And using the `show` and `hide`, you can display the relevant results. Below is an updated code:

```js
$("#searchInput").on('keyup', function() {
  var searchValue = $(this).val();
  searchAndFilter(searchValue)
});

function searchAndFilter(searchTerm) {
  if (searchTerm == '') {
    $("#fruits li").hide()
  } else {
    $("#fruits li").each(function() {
      var currentText = $(this).text();
      currentText = currentText.toUpperCase();
      searchTerm = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
      if (currentText.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0) {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fruits li").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search fruits">

<ul id="fruits">
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Grape</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Firstly it's not working! And second you are using JQuery when the question was all in pure javascript

Comment: What is not working? And secondly, this question is tagged JQuery.

Comment: Your answer is totally wrong. When user search it doesn't show answers because it's case-sensitive. And more important results are not hidden when the input is empty :)

Comment: And if you are curious how you can fix it here you have a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tnw586h4/9/

Comment: @edisoni.1337. great. I will try using this jQuery instead of JS

Comment: @edisoni.1337 - I never said, you're code is wrong or denied. I just proposed my answer. Lets not be rude. :)

Comment: @MilanChheda tagged jQuery, to see if we can achieve the same using that.

Comment: Sure @theKing. And my code confirms that it works and can achieve the result using JQuery.

Comment: I am not being rude but just i don't know how you post code here without even trying it. At least when you can't try your code leave a note that you haven't tried this code :)

Comment: The code was tried and it does work. You can very well test yourself.

Comment: Yes now that i said you where are the problems it's working but before it wasn't working so there is nothing wrong :)

Answer (score -2):

You obviously got this from w3schools meaning you did copy n' paste. You should have edited it more, because the one in w3schools shows all the items both at beginning and end. So the best solution, is to add an if...else statement like this:

```js
    if(input.value.length === false) {
        ul.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block"
    }
```

Or alternatively, you can use a switch statement.

Comment: Please see the @edison-biba's accepted answer 3 years ago. The issue was not that copy pasted code, it was about targeting a wrong element in the code.