# How to hide search results when clearing out in the input search box? JavaScript Only Please

Tags: javascript, list, search, filter, listitem

How do you clear search results when clearing out inside the input text box? I have tried this answer on stackoverflow- [How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055107/). Unfortunately, it does not work in this particular coding

```js
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  
  // this wil grab all <li> elements from all <ul> elements on the page
  // however, you will want to specify a unique attribute for only the elements you wish to include
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  

  
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    if (el.innerText.indexOf(query) !== -1)
      el.style.display = 'block';
    else
      el.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myUL, #myUL2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header), #myUL2 li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Test Search
</h2>

<p>
How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a> <div>
  description
  </div>
  
  <div>
  another description
  </div>
  
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a> ss</li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL2" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please use JavaScript only. Thank you for any assistance. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding this three lines:

```
let status = query === "" ? "none" : "block" //If input value is empty, set to "none"
document.querySelector("#myUL").style.display = status;
document.querySelector("#myUL2").style.display = status;
```

This will hide both of your divs whenever your input is empty. Otherwise, it will always be shown.

Look at the new example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;

  // this wil grab all <li> elements from all <ul> elements on the page
  // however, you will want to specify a unique attribute for only the elements you wish to include
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  let status = query==="" ? "none" : "block"
  document.querySelector("#myUL").style.display = status;
  document.querySelector("#myUL2").style.display = status;

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    if (el.innerText.indexOf(query) !== -1)
      el.style.display = 'block';
    else
      el.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myUL,
#myUL2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#myUL li,
#myUL2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#myUL li,
#myUL2 li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header),
#myUL2 li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Test Search
</h2>
<p>
  How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a>
    <div>
      description
    </div>
    <div>
      another description
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a> ss</li>
  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="myUL2" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this one out. I am using Nikhil's answer that's down below. I am a beginner of JavaScript and all of your answers on this forum will help me learn.

Comment: @MichelleDo glad to help, happy coding!

Comment: Hi this turned out to be the best answer after doing so much testing this morning. Thank  you so much @k3llydev ! I really appreciate it. It required all what I needed for project.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if `query` is defined and not empty when displaying or hiding an element.

```
if (query && el.innerText.indexOf(query) !== -1)
```

When search box is cleared, `query` will be empty and this condition evaluates to `false` and all elements will be hidden.

**Live Example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  
  // this wil grab all <li> elements from all <ul> elements on the page
  // however, you will want to specify a unique attribute for only the elements you wish to include
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    if (query && el.innerText.indexOf(query) !== -1)
      el.style.display = 'block';
    else
      el.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myUL, #myUL2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header), #myUL2 li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Test Search
</h2>

<p>
How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a> <div>
  description
  </div>
  
  <div>
  another description
  </div>
  
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a> ss</li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL2" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, recommended reading: [JavaScript Truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. Thank you. Thank you!! Something that simple. Definitely this is what I was looking for.  Thank you Nikhil and k3llydev for the reading suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset all of the elements before applying your filter logic that decides which elements to show. Here's an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
  
  // Reset all the elements.
  elements.forEach(li => li.style.display = 'none');
  
  // Show the elements that contain the query text.
  elements
    .filter(li => query && li.innerText.indexOf(query) >= 0)
    .forEach(li => li.style.display = 'block'); 
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myUL, #myUL2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#myUL li, #myUL2 li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header), #myUL2 li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Test Search
</h2>

<p>
How to hide the List items from Search Filter, when search input field is cleared?</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a> <div>
  description
  </div>
  
  <div>
  another description
  </div>
  
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a> ss</li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL2" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

This example uses the array `filter()` and `forEach()` methods. You can learn about those [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), respectively. Otherwise, feel free to use your loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply and reading suggestions. I will try this one out. I am using Nikhil's answer that's down below. I am a beginner of JavaScript and all of your answers on this forum will help me learn.

Comment: @MichelleDo - No problem. Good luck with your project.